# Is this a mistranslation due to misunderstanding the British accent and English contractions?

Tags: traducción, pronunciación, fonética

In "Treasure Island" this:

*"I have a son of my own," said he, "as like you as two blocks, and he's all the pride of my 'art.*

...is translated as:

*Yo tengo un hijo de tu edad, añadió, que se te parece como un motón á otro, y te aseguro que ya es él el orgullo de mi arte.*

...but shouldn't it be:

*Yo tengo un hijo de tu edad, añadió, que se te parece como un motón á otro, y te aseguro que ya es él el orgullo de mi corazon.*

IOW, "'art" is the phonetic way of writing the British pronunciation of "heart" rather than being the word "art"

### UPDATE

Ben Jonson wrote a poem in which he calls his son his "best piece of poetry." So there would be some basis for somebody calling his son 'the pride of my art' but you wouldn't expect such poetic speech from a buccaneer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a Native Spanish speaker, and from my own perspective, the phrase should be written as follows:

**"Yo tengo un hijo de tu edad, añadió, que se te parece un montón, y te aseguro que él, es el orgullo de mi corazón."**

**Motón** is misspelled. Should be "montón" which is a colloquial expression for "a lot".

**Corazón** needs accent in the last 'o'.

The original English phrase however uses the expression "like two blocks".
Which could be translated to the following metaphor usual saying:

"como dos gotas de agua".

"Like two drops of water" that is, which is a more used expression when comparing 2 entities which both look a lot the same.

Also "de tu edad" is really not present in the original English phrase.
which should be "from your age".

So you could also translate it as:

"Yo tengo un hijo propio, añadió, que luce como tú, como dos gotas de agua; y él es el orgullo de mi corazón".

Which I believe should be the most accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that seems to be the case.